# naming blocks in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

It is not uncommon to see iOS development advice along the lines of:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // work in background
    NSLog(@"%s work", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // update UI on main queue
        NSLog(@"%s updateUI", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    });
});
```

This is great, but it can be tough to debug when something goes wrong. Looking at the output:

```
AppName[1051:4013] __47-[Classname methodName]_block_invoke_0 work
AppName[1051:907] __block_global_0 updateUI
```

The first log line has the class and method names so we have some hope of tracking down an issue in the outer block (hopefully we haven't defined many blocks in that method), but the second log-line (from the inner block)? Good luck, especially if you've used this pattern a lot in your app.

Is there a way to give blocks names which will help us identify their source locations in console output and crash logs?

Comment: Alternatively, you can set a breakpoint in the block and the debugger will spew at you a stack trace when it's reached (which is IME more helpful than `NSLog` in most cases).

Comment: I use breakpoints, too, and have never felt disadvantaged by blocks.

Comment: I don't think there is built in naming of blocks, but you can certainly name queues, which gets you part of the way. That shows up in the debugger and you can include that in the NSLog statement. Alternatively, you can use `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`, too. Perhaps define your own macro which is a combination of the above.

Comment: Um, why don't you just print a string that's meaningful to you instead of `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`?

Answer (score 4):

Blocks, once copied, become instances of NSBlock, which means that we can then use the runtime to add all sorts of nice things to it. Here is an example:

```
@protocol QuietTheCompiler<NSObject>
- (NSString*) prettyBlockDescription;
@end

static id beautifyBlockDescription(id block, NSString *name)
{
    static void *kAssocObjectPrettyBlockDescription = "A";
    Class blockClass = [block class];

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

        SEL    descrSel     = @selector(description);
        SEL    prettySel    = @selector(prettyBlockDescription);
        Method descrMethod  = class_getInstanceMethod(blockClass, descrSel);
        IMP    originalImpl = class_getMethodImplementation(blockClass, descrSel);

        IMP prettyImpl = imp_implementationWithBlock(^(id self_) {
            id value = objc_getAssociatedObject(self_, kAssocObjectPrettyBlockDescription);
            return (value != nil)? value : originalImpl(self_, descrSel);
        });

        if (class_addMethod(blockClass, prettySel, prettyImpl, method_getTypeEncoding(descrMethod))) {
            IMP newImpl = imp_implementationWithBlock(^(id self_) {
                return [self_ prettyBlockDescription];
            });
            class_replaceMethod(blockClass, descrSel, newImpl, method_getTypeEncoding(descrMethod));
        }
    });

    NSString *description = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@: %p name=%@>",NSStringFromClass(blockClass),block,name];
    objc_setAssociatedObject(block, kAssocObjectPrettyBlockDescription, description, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);

    return block;
}


int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        int (^block1)(int,NSString*) = ^(int i, NSString *fmt) {
            return i;
        };

        id blockObject1 = beautifyBlockDescription([block1 copy], @"Hello");

        int (^block2)(int,NSString*) = ^(int i, NSString *fmt) {
            return i+1;
        };

        id blockObject2 = [block2 copy];

        NSLog(@"Block 1: %@", blockObject1);
        NSLog(@"Block 1: %@", blockObject2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output of this program:

```
// Sample Output
2013-03-31 12:34:48.984 Dummy[1231:303] Block 1: <__NSGlobalBlock__: 0x1000059d0 name=Hello>
2013-03-31 12:34:48.987 Dummy[1231:303] Block 1: <__NSGlobalBlock__: 0x100005a10>
```

I would suggest that you wrap the beautifyBlockDescription function in a macro so that for release code it just returns the block.

Comment: Probably too complicated but very interesting!

Comment: It is a bit complicated but playing around with the runtime is never really simple. This is also the type of function that fits nicely in a little library that gets re-used over and over...

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is use functions instead of blocks, and `dispatch_async_f` instead of `dispatch_async`. The tradeoffs are significant though, as you lose the inline code nature of blocks, and the ability to capture state without having to marshal it through a context pointer.

You could also just declare the inner block outside the outer block and stash it in a local variable. A bit less concise, but it would tag it with the enclosing method's name like the outer block.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using https://github.com/conradev/BlockTypeDescription to improve the readability of logs during development. However, this library replaces a method on the private NSBlock class, you should never try to use it in an appstore binary or it will likely be rejected. Which means you can't improve the crashlogs you get from Apple.